# How to connect 2 many to many fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 many to many fields in models and i want to connect them to each other i mean if i connect user in Admin Model with Counter Party i cant see that in Counter Party admin

How can i do that?

When im trying to do that it shows only in 1 model

models.py

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    user_counter = models.ManyToManyField('CounterParty', blank=True, verbose_name='Контрагенты пользователя')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}'


class CounterParty(models.Model):
    GUID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Наименование')
    customer = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Заказчик')
    contractor = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Подрядчик')
    counter_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='counter_user',
                                          verbose_name='Пользователи контрагента')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Контрагент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Контрагенты'

    def __str__(self):
        return
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser, CounterParty, ObjectList, SectionList
from authentication.models import User
from authentication.admin import UserAdmin


class CustomUserInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CustomUser
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (CustomUserInLine,)


@admin.register(CounterParty)
class CounterPartyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

[user admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKfzF.png)

[counter party admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiicH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not want to have these kinds of references with ManyToMany. Ideally you would have a one sided reference.

You can do an inline in your admin like this:

```
class CustomUserInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = "CustomUser.user_counter.through"
```

Here are the docs for inline M2M in the admin: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)

Comment: so i need only 1 many to many field right in both models?

Comment: Yes indeed, you can use the reverse relation like this: `counter_party. user_counter_set` assuming counter_party is your CounterParty object. Here are the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#:~:text=Reverse%20m2m%20queries%20are%20supported%20(i.e.%2C%20starting%20at%20the%20table%20that%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20have%20a%20ManyToManyField)%3A